Deleting all adjacent small road lines perpendicular to buffer using ArcGIS Pro
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2. I clipped all road lines inside a buffer. However, some small adjacent road segments are within the network.
Is there a tool or option that can get rid of this small part of the road?
It will take too much time to do it manually.


If you recalculate road lengths, then select all that are under a length approximately equal to your buffer, that might get you most of the way and then add some manual subtractions or additions to finish?

They are short lines with dangle. So use feature to vertices tool to select them. Dissolve to single part first
